# How do you use programmatically send a passphrase to GPG for git commit signing?

Tags: git, gnupg, passphrase

I'd like to sign each of my git commits but I don't want to type my passphrase every 10 minutes. I store my passphrase in a password manager and have CLI access to the passphrase via that manager.

How do I get Git to call GPG in such a way that GPG pulls the passphrase from my password manager directly, rather than me copying it from my password manager and pasting it into the GPG prompt?

Comment: Linus Torvalds on commit signing: "*Signing each commit is totally stupid. It just means that you automate it, and you make the signature worth less. It also doesn't add any real value, since the way the git DAG-chain of SHA1's work, you only ever need one signature to make all the commits reachable from that one be effectively covered by that one. So signing each commit is simply missing the point.*" Found in https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/212216

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
### Git GPG Wrapper ###
#
# A program used by Git to wrap calls to GPG.
#
# This program pulls the GPG passphrase from the STDOUT of a second program and
# passes the passphrase as a flag value to GPG. This program can be used in
# place of gpg by Git to offload passphrase management to another program (eg.
# LastPass, 1Password, etc).
#
# The secondary program (by default called ~/.gpg.echo-passphrase) can be as simple as:
#
#     OP_ITEM_NAME="GPG Passphrase"
#     op item get $OP_ITEM_NAME --format=json \
#         | jq -r '.fields[] | select(.id == "password").value'
#
# The secondary program path can be specified with the env var $GPG_ECHO_PASSPHRASE_BIN.
#
# The .gitconfig file would be updated to point to this file. Assuming git.gpg
# is locatable on $PATH.
#
#     [gpg]
#         program = gpg.git
#
#
# Uncomment this line to view what args are being passed by Git to GPG.
#
# echo "$@" >> /tmp/git.gpg.args.txt
#
# Examples are:
#     --status-fd=2 -bsau 1AB00E2439AB1403!
#     --keyid-format=long --status-fd=1 --verify /var/folders/8c/lvrg9rk97wbcy8b44h_llb9w0000gn/T//.git_vtag_tmpZ6shbe -

GPG_ECHO_PASSPHRASE_BIN="${GPG_ECHO_PASSPHRASE_BIN:-~/.gpg.echo-passphrase}"

gpg \
    --pinentry-mode loopback \
    --passphrase $($GPG_ECHO_PASSPHRASE_BIN) \
    $@
```

https://github.com/logston/dotfiles/blob/master/git-commands/.git-commands/gpg.git

Each time I need to commit, my password manager (if open) supplies the password to Git. If the password manager is not open, Git correctly fails to sign the commit.